# Reputation/Privilege Breakdown

Tags: support, user-interface, privileges

It used to be that when I clicked on my rep link, I could see a breakdown of what rep was required to have certain privileges. Is that page gone? Has it moved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges -

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I'd thank you, but that one made me feel down right silly :)

Comment: You can shoot it down now (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's available in the dropdown before your username at the top of every page.

Answer (score 9):

It is right here:
[image]